# Показ всех программ в автозагрузке

Tags: c#, wmi

Здравствуйте.Есть код,который показывает список программ в автозагрузке. Но проблема в том,что в результате выходит не полный список,а только те программы,которые сейчас работают. Как сделать вывод всех,даже которые отключены?

Например в Windows при открытии через msconfig >> Автозагрузка там показан список включенных и отключенных программ. Как замутить подобное?

Код который сейчас у меня:

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView3.Items.Clear();
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_StartupCommand");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { (queryObj["Name"].ToString()), (queryObj["Location"].ToString()) });
            listView3.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }

    }
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

MsConfig хранит свои данные в реестре и явно сам использует аналогичные средства поиска программ с автозапуском

Вот тут покопайтесь, много интересного, но так или иначе, это никак не связано с Вашей задачей по сути)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig\
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey);
var autostartProgramNames = key.GetValueNames();
```

Comment: Вот только это лишь один из многих источников программ для автозапуска...